# Using HOST_WWW_ROOT on the MAMP stack

Tags: php, mysql, localhost, mamp

I'm currently trying to teach myself PHP and MySQL using the MAMP stack.  Everything has been going good up until I came across this problem.

I am reading a book and completing the exercises as I go and I'm at the point where I have to let the user upload an image and then store that image on the web server.  The book states that to do that, you make use of `HOST_WWW_ROOT` to set the location for the web files that will be uploaded.

I have done exactly how the book says to, however it is not working.

Is it possible to use this `HOST_WWW_ROOT` on localhost or can it only be used on a live server?

Comment: It seems that there are some concepts you need to have in your background before. What is `HOST_WWW_ROOT`? Did you read the side notes in the book?

Comment: From what I have read, it is where the web files are kept.  However, I don't know how this differs from SITE_ROOT.  Do you have any references to direct me to that I could learn more from?  The book doesn't really expand with it too much.

Comment: I think you're a little confused. Let me elaborate my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every book will use something like `SITE_ROOT` or `HOST_WWW_ROOT` to refer to the location where your web server's public directory is located at.

MAMP FAQ:

> **Where should I store my HTML and PHP pages?**
>
> By default, PHP and HTML Pages should be stored inside the MAMP "htdocs" folder which is located in the MAMP Application directory /Applications/MAMP. This folder is called "Document Root". You can change the path for the Document Root in the MAMP application's Preferences Panel:

[image]

Now, depending on the platform you are developing your application on, some books would use something like `SITE_ROOT`, `WWW_PUB`, `WWW_ROOT`, etc. but they all refer, as you said, to the location where your 'web files' are.

See if there are some side notes indicating the book conventions.

Comment: Saul, thanks for taking the time to answer. That's actually the directory listing that I thought was the right one and the one I am using.  However, when I submit the form I get an error that the file cannot be moved to the suggested directory.

Comment: Wow, my apologies. I just read through all of my code very carefully and found that there was one letter that should have been UPPERCASE but was lowercase. Really stupid error.  Sorry for all of the hassle, but thank you for all of your help, I really appreciate it.